# Using non-type template argument during partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following `struct`s:

```cpp
//Implementations provided elsewhere

struct A {  A(int i, double d, std::string s);  /* ... */ };
struct B {  B(double d1, double d2);            /* ... */ };
```

I have two conversion classes whose template signatures look like:

```cpp
TupleAs< A, int, double, std::string > via1 { ... };
ArrayAs< B, double, 2 >                via2 { ... };
```

Predictably, `TupleAs` converts a triplet of `int`,`double`, and `std::string` values into an object of type `A`.  Similarly, `ArrayAs` converts a pair of two `double` values into an object of type `B`.  (And yes, there are reasons why I cannot call the `A` and `B` constructors directly.)

**Improving the syntax**

I would like to change the syntax so I can do the following:

```cpp
TupleAs< A(int,double,std::string) > via1 { ... };
ArrayAs< B(double,2) >               via2 { ... };
```

which, I think, is more descriptive of a conversion process.  The `TupleAs` template declaration and corresponding partial specialization would look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct TupleAs;

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct TupleAs<T(Args...)> { ... };
```

**Compiler errors**

However, if I try to do something similar with the `ArrayAs` version:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct ArrayAs;

template <typename T, typename U, unsigned N>
struct ArrayAs<T(U,N)> { ... };
```

I get the following errors in clang (3.6) when trying to instantiate it (`ArrayAs< B(double,2)> test;`):

```
typeAs.cpp:14:22: error: unknown type name 'N'
  struct ArrayAs<T(U,N)>{
                     ^
typeAs.cpp:14:10: warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
  struct ArrayAs<T(U,N)>{
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
typeAs.cpp:13:45: note: non-deducible template parameter 'N'
  template<typename T, typename U, unsigned N>
                                            ^
```

The gcc error diagnostic is a little different, but I won't post it here.

I admit that my templating skills should be better than they are, and I also concede that an analogous `std::function<B(double,2)>` declaration clearly is nonsense.  But can someone tell me why the particular syntax I'm trying to achieve is not allowed?  I looked through the C++14 standard and had trouble finding the relevant portion, and I'm having trouble interpreting the clang diagnostic message.

Comment: You're specializing on a function type. A function type is of the form `type(types...)`, there's no room for an integer. Said the other way around, the `B(double, 2)` syntax makes no sense in C++, in any context. The error message could admittedly make more sense.

Comment: Do you need the `2` to be a compile-time parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specialize `TupleAs`:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct TupleAs<T(Args...)>
```

You are basically overloading the notation for a function. You are specializing on a *function* that takes `Args...` and returns a `T`. That is a type. You may not be using that function as a function, or really ever think about it as being a type, but that is what it is.

On the other hand, here:

```
template <typename T, typename U, unsigned N>
struct ArrayAs<T(U,N)> { ... };
```

There is no such thing as a function that takes `N`. It could take `unsigned`, but it can't take a *value*. There is just no such reasonable thing. From your example, `B(double, 2)` simply does not make sense. At best, you could write something that would allow:

```
template <unsigned N> using size_ = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

ArrayAs< B(double,size_<2>) >
```

Or even:

```
ArrayAs< B(std::array<double, 2>) >
```

since now we're back to using types everywhere. Whether you prefer that or not is personal preference.

The key here is that types are first-class citizens when it comes to all things template metaprogramming, and values should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @Yakk `ArrayAs<B(double(&)[3]>` does, but *yuck*. Blame array decay :p

Comment: Yes, fundamentally I am trying to specialize on a function type.  That's the bit I needed to hear. Thanks.

Comment: @Barry doesn't work as it needs a `decltype` around it.  ( sketched it out, built it, and suck ) -- literals are values, not types (d'oh).

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T> struct ArrayAs;

template <typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
struct ArrayAs<T(std::array<U,N>)> { ... };
```

works, as would:

```
template<class T>
struct to_array;
template<class T, size_t N>
struct to_array< T[N] > { using type = std::array<T, N>; };
template<class T>
using arr = typename to_array<T>::type;
```

then:

```
ArrayAs< Bob( arr<int[3]> ) > some_var;
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/520fd920090340d4).

Sadly, directly using `ArrayAs< Bob( int[3] ) >` doesn't work due to how arrays in function types decay to pointers.

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying the array-subscripting syntax. Thanks for that.  But alas because of the decay ...